# How to convert from any type to std::string in C++

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, tostring

I'm making a LinkedList class using template, since I want to use it for whatever type I need afterwards

```
template <typename T> class LinkedList {}
```

I'm trying to make a function that adds all the elements of a list into a string:

```
std::string join(const char *seperator)
{
    std::string str;
    auto curr = this->head;
    while (curr)
    {
        str += std::to_string(curr->value);
        if (curr->next)
            str += seperator;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return str;
}
```

It works with the types I tested (int, double, float...) but doesn't work with std::string, the `to_string()` function generates an error

> Error C2665   'std::to_string': none of the 9 overloads could convert
> all the argument types

I assume it doesn't work with other types. so, can you provide a general method to convert from any type to std::string.

Comment: There is no general method to convert any type into a string.

Comment: There is no concept of "any type" in C++ that can be used to convert a data structure to a string. The helper function `std::to_string()` will convert the base data types only. You would need to create your own custom function for formatting your custom data structure to a string. It also makes sense that `to_string()` has no overload for `std::string()` as it would be a pointless no-op.

Comment: Keyword: serialization

Comment: @NathanOliver Technically, there is a way to convert any type to string: `template<class T> std::string(const T&) { return "some_object"; }` Whether its useful is another question.

Comment: @Sharry You can use SFINAE or `if constexpr` to avoid calling `to_string()` on `std::string` data.  For anything else, you would have to provide an overload of `to_string()` for any other type beyond fundamental language types, or else use `std::ostream` and `operator<<` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no universal way to convert an object of arbitrary type to a string in C++. But the most commonly supported facility for outputting data as strings are output streams. So, you could use [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) like this:

```
std::string join(const char *seperator)
{
    std::ostringstream strm;
    auto curr = this->head;
    while (curr)
    {
        strm << curr->value;
        if (curr->next)
            strm << seperator;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return strm.str();
}
```

Note that for this to work the type `T` should provide an `operator<<` overload that takes `std::ostream&` as the first argument. All arithmetic types, C-style strings and `std::string` are supported by this facility, but not all user-defined types may be.